# JS triangle rotating around midpoint

Tags: javascript, math, svg, rotation, trigonometry

I'm trying to rotate a triangle around it's midpoint... the midpoint is calculated and stored in an array in this format:
midpoint = [midpointX,midpointY];
the points are stored the same way as points.a = [x,y] and points.b and points.b, etc...

**here's the formula I'm using for rotating point A for example, and the value returned is null for some reason? (p.s. rotationAngle is in degrees)**

new X = `(midpoint[0] + (points.a[0]-midpoint[0])*Math.cos(Math.PI*(trig.rotation)/180) - (points.a[1]-midpoint[1])*Math.sin(Math.PI*(trig.rotation)/180))`

new Y = `(midpoint[1] + (points.a[1]-midpoint[1])*Math.cos(Math.PI*(rotationAngle)/180) + (points.a[0]-midpoint[0])*Math.sin(Math.PI*(rotationAngle)/180))`

Edit: Forgot to mention this is inside an ng-attr

Comment: @gandaliter sorry forgot the code tags

Comment: Strange. It shouldn't come back null unless one of the values used in the calculation is null, and `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` can't return null. You could try splitting the calculation up with intermediate variables and testing for null at each line, to see where the problem is.

Comment: Midpoint refers to [centroid](http://easycalculation.com/analytical/learn-centroid.php)? Or the [midpoint therom](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/geometry/polygons/the-midpoint-theorem) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few problems with the snippet that you have:

- `new` should be `var`: You are storing the computed value into X and Y.
- `trig.rotation` = `rotationAngle`: Just pick one if they are the same variable. You have `X` using `trig.rotation` and `Y` using `rotationAngle`

I just tried this with `var`, and it works fine for me when everything is defined. You should try to log the variables to see if all of them are defined by using a `console.log` function.

```
console.log(midpoint,trig.rotation,rotationAngle,points.a);
var X = (midpoint[0] + (points.a[0]-midpoint[0])*Math.cos(Math.PI*(trig.rotation)/180) - (points.a[1]-midpoint[1])*Math.sin(Math.PI*(trig.rotation)/180));
var Y = (midpoint[1] + (points.a[1]-midpoint[1])*Math.cos(Math.PI*(rotationAngle)/180) + (points.a[0]-midpoint[0])*Math.sin(Math.PI*(rotationAngle)/180));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with formula... I was using ng-attr to calculate and that doesn't take Math.cos or Math.PI so. Sorry for lack of detail =/